# wait on database engine handle recovery failed

Tags: sql-server

I am installing SQL 2012 and getting error wait on database engine handle recovery failed,  changed the credentials to `"NT Authority\NETWORK SERVICE"` but getting same error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have TLS 1.2 enabled, but:

- you're not running a build of SQL Server 2012 that *supports* TLS 1.2, and / or
- you're not running a version of the .NET Framework that supports TLS 1.2

The following KB lists out the 2012 builds that support TLS 1.2:

[TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server)
- SP2 
  - 11.0.5644.2 (CU 10) or
  - 11.0.5352.0 (GDR update)
- SP3
  - 11.0.6518.0 (CU 3)
  - 11.0.6216.27 (GDR update)

The .NET Framework version you need depends on your Windows Server version, and is listed out in the following KB article:

[FIX: Error when you install SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2014 on a server that has TLS 1.2 enabled](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135769/fix-error-when-you-install-sql-server-2012-or-sql-server-2014-on-a-ser)

It's also possible that you don't have TLS enabled at all, which is required to run the product.  So the solution may be that you just need to enabled TLS 1.0 or SSL 3.0 (although 1.2 is recommended).